# reindex with sunspot Error - Connection reset by peer - retrying... rake aborted! Connection refused -

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sunspot-rails, sunspot-solr

When I run the reindex command rake rake sunspot:solr:reindex it dosn't work. The solr server stop with a fatal error and reindex showing this

**Error - Connection reset by peer - retrying... rake aborted! Connection refused -**

Please help me.

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ruby-sunspot/SO_44I0t1Uw might be helpful

Comment: your question is too bogus, could you be more explicit? do you have a trace? is your solr instance running?